# Mocking complex methods on structs used in a void function

Tags: go, mocking, tdd

My problem isn't terribly complex. I'll write a simple example first, and then show the real code after in case I missed any subtleties.

So I have a third-party library:

```
// Third party library
type ThirdPartyFoo struct {}    
func (t *ThirdPartyFoo) DoFoo () *ThirdPartyFoo {
    println("I'm a third party library!")
    return t
}
```

And I want to use that library to invoke `DoFoo()`:

```
type MyThing struct {
    TheFoo ThirdPartyFoo
}

func (myThing *MyThing) WhichLib () {
    myThing.TheFoo.DoFoo()
}
```

And I want to test it with a mocked version of `ThirdPartyFoo` because, how else am I supposed to verify that `DoFoo()` was A) invoked, B) invoked with the correct parameters, and C) `MyThing` responds correctly based on different return values?

I tried using an interface inside `MyThing` instead of directly depending on `ThirdPartyFoo`...

```
type IThirdPartyFoo interface {
    DoFoo() *IThirdPartyFoo
}

type MyThingWithI struct {
    TheFoo IThirdPartyFoo
}

func (myThing *MyThingWithI) WhichLib () {
    myThing.TheFoo.DoFoo()
}
```

And then invoking the function...

```
func main() {
    realFoo := ThirdPartyFoo{}
    realThing := MyThingWithI{
        TheFoo: &realFoo,
    }
    realThing.WhichLib()
}
```

But it fails at runtime:

```
proxyutils/serviceregistrar.go:44:9: cannot use &realFoo (type *ThirdPartyFoo) as type IThirdPartyFoo in field value:
        *ThirdPartyFoo does not implement IThirdPartyFoo (wrong type for DoFoo method)
                have DoFoo() *ThirdPartyFoo
                want DoFoo() IThirdPartyFoo
```

So... I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, and another hour writing up this post... and I'm still lost. The only solution I can come up with is to completely wrap the third party library, like so:

```
type IThirdPartyFooWrapper interface {
    DoFoo() IThirdPartyFooWrapper
}

type ThirdPartyFooWrapper struct {
    IThirdPartyFooWrapper

    ThirdPartyFoo ThirdPartyFoo
}

func (w *ThirdPartyFooWrapper) DoFoo () IThirdPartyFooWrapper {
    w.ThirdPartyFoo.DoFoo()
    return w
}

type MyThingWithI struct {
    TheFooWrapper IThirdPartyFooWrapper
}

func (myThing *MyThingWithI) WhichLib() {
    myThing.TheFooWrapper.DoFoo()
}
```

But there are SO MANY levels of indirection already that I really hate to add this one. This is what mocking was made for, but it seems the Go language has completely screwed over any poor schmuck unfortunate enough to have started using a third-party library that isn't making use of interfaces.

And finally, here's my real code. It's the `*mux.Router` as part of `ServiceRegistrar` that is being problematic.

```
package proxyutils

import (
    "errors"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

type IProxyRegistrar interface {
    Register(input Registration) error
}

type ServiceRegistrarFactory struct{}

func (_ *ServiceRegistrarFactory) Build(proxyRegistrar IProxyRegistrar, router *mux.Router) (*ServiceRegistrar, error) {
    if nil == proxyRegistrar {
        return nil, errors.New("cannot create ServiceRegistrar with nil IProxyRegistrar")
    }
    if nil == router {
        return nil, errors.New("cannot create ServiceRegistrar with nil mux.Router")
    }
    return &ServiceRegistrar{
        proxyRegistrar: proxyRegistrar,
        router:         router,
    }, nil
}

type ServiceRegistrar struct {
    proxyRegistrar IProxyRegistrar
    router         *mux.Router
}

func (r *ServiceRegistrar) Register(userRegistration Registration, f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) error {
    err := r.proxyRegistrar.Register(userRegistration)
    if nil == err {
        var route *mux.Route
        if userRegistration.PathIsPrefix {
            route = r.router.PathPrefix(userRegistration.Path)
        } else {
            route = r.router.Path(userRegistration.Path)
        }
        route.Methods(userRegistration.Methods...).HandlerFunc(f)
        return nil
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO the problem lies in mocking itself. You asked: "how else am I supposed to verify that DoFoo() was A) invoked, B) invoked with the correct parameters" and my opinion about this question is: "I don't give a shit. I'm not interested in _how_ the function/method WhichLib comes up with a correct answer, only _that_ it yields proper result." Whether it calls into ThirdPartyFoo or some some mock or an oracle does not matter. If it behave correct it is correct. So: do not mock.

Comment: If the function under test calls into stuff which is low, not idempotent or not available: Provide a fake.

Comment: Can you pass in a real mux.Router that has the behavior you're trying to test? Such as routes with handlers to endpoints you create via httptest.NewServer ? Then you can hit them to verify cases like  when r.router.Path(userRegistration.Path) is called, it goes to a specific URL which fires a handler you have an assert on.

Comment: @bkimble, thanks for the push. I guess I was just too exhausted Friday to actually _look_ at the mux.Route API to see what options I had. By change my function signature from `func (r *ServiceRegistrar) Register(userRegistration Registration, f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) error` to `func (r *ServiceRegistrar) Register(userRegistration Registration, f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) (*mux.Route, error)`, I can actually run assertions on the created Route. And the Route has "getter" methods on it which I can run assertions against.